# How to apply Ito formula to represent a stochastic process as an Ito process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Let $\{W_t : t \geq 0\}$ and $\{\tilde{W_t} : t \geq 0\}$ be two independent Brownian motions. It is not clear to me how to apply Ito formula to represent a process as an Ito process. For instance, I would like to represent the following two processes

$$W(t)^2\tilde{W}(t) - t\quad \text{and}\quad exp[W(t)\tilde{W}(t) - \frac{1}{2}(\tilde{W}(s)^2 + W(s)^2)ds]$$

as Ito processes.

Can someone please show me how to proceed ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where exactly did you get stuck? Note that you have two independent Brownian motions, so you will need the multi-dimensional Ito formula.

Comment: Can I use the following version of Ito formula in this case ? Let $f: \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, (x, y) \mapsto f(x, y)$ be a function of class $C^2$. Then $$f(W_t, \tilde{W_t}) = f(0,0) + \int_0^ t \frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(W_t, \tilde{W_t}) dW_t+ \int_0^ t \frac{\partial}{\partial y} f(W_t, \tilde{W_t}) d\tilde{W_t}+ \frac{1}{2}(\int_0^ t \frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(W_t, \tilde{W_t}) dx + \int_0^ t \frac{\partial}{\partial y} f(W_t, \tilde{W_t}) dy)$$

Comment: Not quite. First of all, your first function also depends on $t$, so you need to include the $t$-derivative. Second, the term with the $1/2$ factor in front is wrong. The quadratic cross-variation between the two Brownian motions is zero, but the quadratic variation of each one is $t$, not $x$ or $y$, and you need second partial derivatives. Also, $t$ should not both be integration variable and upper limit of the integral. (Check the formula in a textbook or online.) Otherwise you are on the right track.

Comment: Can you maybe give me the right formula that I need or recommend a link/book?

Comment: I would just check Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4_calculus. See the short paragraph "Ito's Lemma", it has the formula in differential form, without $t$-dependence. However, if you have explicit $t$-dependence, there is just another term $f_t(X_t) \, dt$ added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $w,b$ be Wiener processes and let $t$ be the time variable. Then a function $f$ (with certain nice conditions) that is a function of $(w,b,t)$, will be equal to (using the Ito rule):

$
d f(w_t,b_t,t) = \partial_w [f] dw_t + \frac{1}{2} \partial_{ww} [f] d \langle w,w \rangle_t + \partial_b [f] db_t + \frac{1}{2} \partial_{bb} [f] d \langle b,b \rangle_t + \partial_{bw} [f] d \langle b,w \rangle_t + \partial_t [f] dt
$

Let $z_t = w_t^2 b_t -t$. The above formula applied to $z$ gives us

$
dz_t=d[w_t^2b_t-t] = 2w_tb_t dw_t+w_t^2 db_t+(b_t-1)dt.
$

You have made a mistake in defining the second process - the $ds$ term cannot exist unless it is under an integral - which is missing.